# IE prompts SP site twice and renders error

Tags: 2010, internet-explorer

This problem has been plaguing me for quite some time. I have done some research but can't come to a conclusion that I can execute. I have IE10 and when I browse some sites in SP I get prompted twice by IE with message below.

[image]

After the second time IE renders a page shown below:

[image]

On the page above, when I look at the url, I get res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm# followed by my site's Url. It happens intermittently but I have noticed when going to Site Permissions that it consistently produces the above mentioned issue. Also, I am the only one experiencing this. I know I can switch to another browser no problem. I prefer IE when using SP. Has anyone ran into this or has any experience? If so, may I get some advice on what I can do to rectify the dilemma?

Comment: Since you are the only one experiencing this issue, it seems specific to your browser. Have you tried deleting your IE browser cache, history, cookies, etc.?

Comment: Yes. That was actually the first thing I have done but still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (same message, same error page), and I noticed that the message appears 1 to 2 seconds after the mouse pointer hovers over the "modified by" or "created by" field. Reinstalling IE or switching to the intranet zone does not solve anything.

I advise to work around this problem by **hiding these *Created By* / *Modified By* columns in the Sharepoint view** :

1. On the ribbon at the top under list/library, click on the *Modify view* button. A *Settings : Edit View* page appears.

[image]

2. In the  *Columns* section Uncheck the *Created By* / *Modified By* items
3. Save : click the *OK* button

[image: Settings : Edit View to hide Modified by column]

Answer (score 0):

I have come to find out that repairing Office was the solution to my problem.

On Windows 7, got to *Control Panel* then *Programs and Features*. Select the Microsoft Office line and clic on the *Change* function. Select the *Repair* option.
[image]

See the [Fix Internet Explorer Crashes with SharePoint 2013 Online Presence Indicators](https://sympmarc.com/2013/11/29/fix-internet-explorer-crashes-with-sharepoint-2013-online-presence-indicators/) article for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Solved: Adding the site to the intranet zone in the browser.

Comment: Site is already in the intranet zone.